# how to remain a specific color in the theme

Tags: jquery, ajax, css, jquery-ui

I have a theme, i want to put addional functionality in it in which a user can select the colour of its own choice from the colour box in the theme and the selected colour should applied to the theme and also the selected colour should remain after the page refreshes. I suceeded in selecting the colour of own choice and the colour applies to the theme but now i face a problem when the user refreshes the page , the selected colour does not remain, so how can i solve this problem? thanks in advance

Comment: God only answer your question

Comment: Save settings in database, although this is a poor question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are many issues with the way you have asked the question. Please use the http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and review posts like http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: how can i save settings in database help me